# Writing prettytable in output file in python

Tags: python, file, output, prettytable

I am parsing through a textfile and extracting the information I need into a prettytable. However, I am unable to write the table out as one table it outputs as a single table for each item.

My code for outputting the table:

```
f = open("out2.txt", "w")
for item in table:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)

f.write("There are %(count)d errors found" %{"count": count})
```

And my output looks like:

[image]

How can i write out the table so that it is one consecutive table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `f.write(table.get_string())` work for you? Instead of iterating through the table and writing each item, just write the table itself?

So something like this, replacing the loop:

```
f = open('out2.txt','wb')
f.write(table.get_string())
f.write('There are %(count)d errors found' % {'count': count})
```

Comment: @KayCarosfeild It looks like you kept the `write` inside the loop. I updated the answer for clarity thinking you want to write the entire table once.

Comment: That works perfectly sorry that was a simple mistake on my behave.